# How to send notes.txt output to a file instead of dumping it to the console?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want Helm to write the output of notes.txt to a local file instead of just dumping it to the console. I want to write a JSON file that is going to be read by another system (that is going to send a Slack message).

If that is not possible is there a separate Helm command that just outputs notes.txt without having to do a full deploy?

I don't want to have to try to capture and parse it out of the entire deployment output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`helm status <release>` will show you the state of a release. This also contains the notes.txt output.

Helm offers the ability to specify the output format of the `helm status <release-name>` command ([doc](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_status/#options)). So by running:

```
$> helm status <release> -o json
```

you will get detailed information about the deployed release in json format:

```
{
  "name": "release",
  "info": {
    "first_deployed": "..",
    "last_deployed": "..",
    "deleted": "",
    "description": "Install complete",
    "status": "deployed",
    "notes": "THIS IS THE FIELD YOU WANT"
  },
  "manifest": "...",
  "version": 1,
  "namespace": "..."
}
```

Depending on the shell you're using, you can then directly save the output in a file ( below for bash ):

```
$> helm status <release> -o json > out.json
```

Or use other mechanism to further process the json file before saving ( like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)):

```
$> helm status <release> -o json | jq -r '.info.notes'
...
[ only the notes part of the release ]
...
```